# Using .NET structures with WINAPI functions

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, pinvoke

Let's say I want to invoke `GetWindowRect` functions. I though that I must create new struct that would represent `RECT`, but this also works:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool GetWindowRect(System.IntPtr hWnd, out Rectangle lpRect);
```

Rectangle is `System.Drawing.Rectangle`. Why does this work, although `Rectangle` is different structure than `RECT`?

In the future, should I be using .NET structs whenever it is possible (like Rectange and Point), or declare new struct for each WinAPI structure?

Comment: "why does this work?": actually, it doesn't. `RECT`'s fields are Left, Top, Right, Bottom, while `Rectangle`'s fields are x, y, width, height. They seem to have the same binary structure, but the fields don't have the same meaning...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code runs, the struct happens to have the same size by accident.  That's not exactly the same thing as "it works".  The Windows RECT structure is **not** identical to the .NET Rectangle structure.  Windows' RECT gives the 4 edges, .NET uses a Point and a Size, big difference.

Just don't ever be shy about declaring the type you really need.  It is a one liner that very easily fits the SO code window, a good standard of measure:

```
 struct RECT { public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom; }
```

One line of code should *never* make you look for the hack :)  Just in case: no, [StructLayout] is not required.  .NET already auto-generates one for struct types.  Already fit as a fiddle as posted.